# Error Installing RVM through Cygwin in Windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, cygwin, rvm

I am attempting to install RVM through Cygwin, following [this tutorial](http://blog.developwithpassion.com/blog/page/2/).

AFter creating the directory and cloning the git repository, I need to run ./osx_or_cygin_kick_off to begin the installation process.

This is the error message I am getting:

```
  $ ./osx_or_cygwin_kick_off
  ./automation/rvm/rvm_install: line 2: $'\r': command not found
  ./automation/rvm/rvm_install: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `$'\r''
  '/automation/rvm/rvm_install: line 3: `install_rvm()
  ./automation/rvm/rvm_install_some_rubies: line 2: $'\r': command not found
  ./automation/rvm/rvm_install_some_rubies: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `$'\r''
  '/automation/rvm/rvm_install_some_rubies: line 3: `install_some_rubies()
```

I read somewhere that converting the files to unix format via doc2unix might solve the problem, but it is only creating more error messages.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm guessing you meant run through `dos2unix`, and that is a way to solve the problem, but since you're having trouble with that, try one of my alternate solutions in the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:**

The problem is that some Cygwin git installations try to do magic linefeed handling.  To fix git so it stops mangling line endings, run:

```
git config --global core.autocrlf false
```

**Original answer made more generic after comment clarification:**

The file contains CRLF (`\r\n`) end-line sequences, which is typical on Windows.  Unix doesn't like it, though; Unix (and Cygwin) want just LF (`\n`).  I'm guessing you cut-and-pasted that file, or downloaded it through some mechanism that appended Windows line endings.

To fix files in Cygwin:

```
tr -d '\r' <filename >filename.tmp
```

Check and make sure filename.tmp looks ok, then:

```
mv -f filename.tmp
```

Alternately, do a browser download and save (rather than cut and paste), or from the Cygwin shell, download using `curl` or `wget`.

In all of the above cases, you probably won't have an executable file (just readable).  You can either make it executable with:

```
chmod 755 filename
```

Or run it through the shell explicitly:

```
sh filename
```

You'll run into this problem often if you use Windows editors to manipulate your Cygwin files.  Editors inside Cygwin will be fine (e.g. Vim).  Optionally, many free Windows editors support Unix line endings.  [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) is a good one with a Unix line-ending option.

Comment: Do I need to do the same process for all the files within the automation/rvm folder as well?

Comment: That depends on how you downloaded them.  If you did it the same way, then probably yes.  You might want to start fresh and do it all from inside Cygwin to be sure, or figure out how to download it all in binary format at once, if possible.

Comment: I got the repository using git clone directly from the Cygwin shell. I have not opened the files in anything except notepad++ (and even then without making any changes to it)

Comment: If you used git clone those files will be ok.

Comment: Sorry, I just reviewed the errors, and the CRLFs are actually in the `automation` files, so no, they're not ok.  See my edit.